# foreground service causes phone reboot - why?

Tags: android, service, reboot

**Short version**: does Android reboot the phone (literally reboot) to get rid of foreground services? If so, in what cases?

**Long version**: I wrote a GPS service which registers itself as a foreground service (in this case this is a good idea - when I run it, it is the single most important thing on my phone ;) ). While testing, this service is a **big resource consumer** - it gets GPS data every second and writes to SQLite DB file on SD card. Later I will use internal memory and make poll times longer, but I need the test data for now.

The service works as intended. I have created an Activity that starts & stops it and the results look fine. But when I kept it running the phone rebooted itself after some time (half an hour or so). Since I never noticed this in normal usage, I am attributing this to my service. However, I have no idea what is causing this - should I request a wakelock for CPU? (if this is the problem, wouldn't phone just shutdown?) Did I run out of memory? Did I use too much battery? (it was half full) Is there a log where I can check why the phone rebooted?

Environment: Xperia X10, Android 2.3.3.

Comment: "does Android reboot the phone (literally reboot) to get rid of foreground services?" -- AFAIK, no. My guess is that you are tripping over some firmware bug with your device.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks! Will try to debug further then. Care to post this as an answer so I can accept it? Btw, great book ("Busy coders guide to android development")! :)

Comment: Done, and thanks for the kind words!

Comment: Did you try looking at your app's metrics with a Task Manager app like System Tuner?  It will tell you in real-time how much CPU and memory it is consuming, and for how long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no. That would be unduly harsh to the user. There is nothing about a foreground service that somehow prevents the OS from terminating its process like any other.

My guess is that you are tripping over some firmware bug with your device.

Answer (score 3):

As others said Android doesn't reboot the phone to get rid of foreground services. Most common reasons I've encountered are:

- Kernel panic due to the error in drivers or memory corruption etc.
- `Watchdog` kills the main thread because of a deadlock and that causes the `Zygote` to restart which is almost like a reboot from the user's view.

Without details or logs there's only a guess. Yet it looks like as your `Service` consumed a lot of resources it could cause a `Watchdog` on `SystemServer` thread to be called and that would lead to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Android docs:

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory